# DJANGO: Trying to save POST data to Student model - IntegrityError

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms

Hi I am trying to save data from a form to Student model; abstract User model.

Please help!

> **PROBLEM**: IntegrityError at /register/ UNIQUE constraint failed:
>   accounts_students.username

Not sure what the problem, in the view i am trying to clean the data and save it to the database.

- **Interestingly, the data is being saved, just the page is not being
  redirected!**

  ```
  from .models import *

  from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm, UserChangeForm

  from betterforms.multiform import MultiModelForm
  from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm

   class RegistrationForm(UserCreationForm): 
      email = forms.EmailField(required=True)

      class Meta:
          model = Students
          fields = (
              'username',
              'first_name',


  'last_name',
              'email',
              'password1',
              'password2',
              'bio',
              'location',
              'birth_date',

          )   

      def save(self, commit=True):
          user = super(RegistrationForm, self).save(commit=False)
          user.first_name = self.cleaned_data['first_name']
          user.last_name = self.cleaned_data['last_name']
          user.email = self.cleaned_data['email']

          if commit:
              user.save()

          return user
  ```

models.py

```
class Students(AbstractUser):
    bio = models.TextField(max_length=500, blank=True)
    location = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True)
    birth_date = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)
```

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render

from django.shortcuts import redirect

from accounts.forms import RegistrationForm, EditProfileForm

from django.contrib.auth.models import User

from accounts.models import Students

from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserChangeForm

from django.http import HttpResponse

from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required

# Create your views here.
# def login(request):
#       return render(request, 'accounts/login.html')

def home(request):
    return render(request, 'accounts/home.html')

def login_redirect(request):
    return redirect('/login/')

def register(request):
    # Once register page loads, either it will send to the server POST data (if the form is submitted), else if it don't send post data create a user form to register
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = RegistrationForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():

            bio = form.cleaned_data['bio']
            location = form.cleaned_data['location']
            birth_date = form.cleaned_data['birth_date']
            form.save()

            Students.objects.create(bio=bio, location=location, birth_date=birth_date)
            # Students.objects.create(user=user)
            return redirect('../home/')
    else:
        #  Create the django default user form and send it as a dictionary in args to the reg_form.html page.
        form = RegistrationForm()
    args = {'form': form}
    return render(request, 'accounts/reg_form.html', args)

@login_required 
def view_profile(request):
    args = {'user': request.user}
    return render(request, 'accounts/profile.html', args)

@login_required 
def edit_profile(request):
     # Handle post request - if the user submits a form change form details and pass the intance user
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = EditProfileForm(request.POST, instance=request.user)

        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect('../profile')
    # Handles the get request - if no post info is submitted then get the form and display it on the edit profile page. 
    else:
        form = EditProfileForm(instance=request.user)
        args = {'form': form}
        return render(request, 'accounts/profile_edit.html', args)
```

Comment: Are you able to post the full traceback?

Comment: Students because it has parent AbstractUser the relationship between the two tables are OnetwoOne so you only need the form.save().In your RegisterView. Because when you create a students instance django automatically creates the User instance.

Comment: Can you please give me an example from the code - i'm not sure how to implement, please! @DimitrisKougioumtzis

Comment: in register function remove this line: Students.objects.create(bio=bio, location=location, birth_date=birth_date)

Comment: @WillKeeling What do you mean by full track back? new to django

Comment: @WillKeeling it worked!!

Comment: Q: I assumed    # Students.objects.create(bio=bio, location=location, birth_date=birth_date)
    creates the first instance... Where else is the student instance being created?